# Child theme breaks after update of master theme

Tags: themes

I have a theme, lets call it Master.
I manually created a child theme, lets call in Master-Child and added some files into it.
All worked well until a notification came that I should update the Master because of a new version.
The child theme has failed to work since.
I get an error message "Master theme does not exist" although "Master" is activated. I tried to rename, capitalize and lowercase all characters.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only string to use the master is  `Template: twentyten` in the style.css if child theme.
Check, if this string correct or has the master change this. If you activate the master as Theme in your install, you find the string also in the database of the WP install, in table options, entry `template` and `stylesheet`; if you have active the child theme, must have the entry `stylesheet` your child theme name; the Master is always on `template`. (for fast check this use the plugin [Adminer](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/adminer/))

example screenshot with the Theme "Black Label" as Master, no Child theme used.
The Screenshot was in Adminer inside the WP install.
[image]

Comment: Thanks, so I need to do a SELECT in WP_OPTIONS table, correct?

Comment: no, with the plugin Adminer can you find this entry in table; you can also use an select, but its more work as activate an plugin and use it. (i have update on the answer with a small screenshot)

Comment: Thanks. I executed the query and reached a similar resultset. I still cannot see the child theme.
How can I access and "fix" my child theme since I cannot activate it?
The child theme does not appear in the result set.
Any ideas?

Comment: please add the result here; and do you have this string in your child theme on the comment string Template: ? After this activate the Child theme.

Comment: Thanks, I checked the actual name and referenced it; that fixed it. Thanks again!